# Extending the ObjectFactory in EclipseLink MOXy

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I have a JAXB model generated from MOXy's version of XJC.  The `xjc:superclass` tag was used in the binding's file so all the objects extend a common class.

```
package my.package
//Base.java
@XmlTransient
public class Base {
    //...
}

//MyTag.java (generated from XJC)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {/*...*/})
@XmlRootElement(name = "myTag")
public class MyTag extends Base {
    //...
}
```

The model nor the schema can be changed, but I can change the Base class.

I need to extend MyTag, as well as some other classes in the model, so I can customize its method behaviors from the Base class.  So I extended MyTag and the other domain classes that needed custom behavior, as well as the ObjectFactory.  These classes exist in a separate Java package.

```
package my.extended.package
//MyTagExtended.java
public class MyTagExtended extends MyTag {
    //...
}

//CustomObjectFactory.java
public class CustomObjectFactory extends ObjectFactory {
    //...

    @Override
    public MyTagExtended createMyTag() {
        return new MyTagExtended();
    }

    //...
}
```

Application code:

```
package application
//Application.java
System.setProperty("org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.annotation.xml-value-extension", "true");
JAXBContext jc = (JAXBContext) JAXBContext.newInstance(XPSObjectFactory.class);
JAXBUnmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
return u.unmarshal(xmlFile);
```

The problem I'm having is MOXy seems to randomly decide whether to call the CustomObjectFactory's or ObjectFactory's methods.

In the CustomObjectFactory class, if I have only one overridden method, that method is always called.  However, when I put in more, MOXy seems to randomly decide whether or not to call ObjectFactory's method's or CustomObjectFactory's.

When I use the same sort of setup with the Oracle's JAXB implementation that's supplied with the JDK, it works fine.  The CustomObjectFactory's methods are always called.

Is there a configuration that needs to be set?  How can I configure MOXy to always use my CustomObjectFactory's methods?

EDIT:
To clarify, here's how I made the same scenario work with Oracle's JAXB implementation:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("my.package");
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
u.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.ObjectFactory", new CustomObjectFactory());
```

I tried to set the ObjectFactory property on the MOXy unmarshaller, but it threw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for MOXy.  I found some information on XmlClassExtractor, which can be used to specify which class to instantiate.  Since I can't modify the domain objects, an XML file was used instead.

I kept the extended classes the same, but modified Application.java and wrote a binding.xml file and a ClassExtractor:

```
package application
//Application.java
System.setProperty("org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.annotation.xml-value-extension", "true");
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "classExtractor.xml");
JAXBContext jc = (JAXBContext) JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[]{CustomObjectFactory.class}, properties);
JAXBUnmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
return u.unmarshal(xmlFile);
```

classExtractor.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings 
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="my.package"
    version="2.3">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="MyTag">
           <xml-class-extractor class="my.extended.package.MyTagClassExtractor"/>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

Class extractor:

```
package my.extended.package
//MyTagExtractor.java
public class MyTagExtractor extends ClassExtractor {
    @Override
    public Class<? extends Base> extractClassFromRow(Record databaseRow, Session session) {
        return MyTagExtended.class;
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but it's quirky and prone to programmer errors since multiple source files have to be edited to get the desired functionality.  Oracle's ObjectFactory property on the unmarshaller was very easy and streamlined.  Does anyone have a better answer?